# storing two different part of a list's elements into a another list

Tags: python, list

So I have a list:

```
myList = ['14:14:12.294 0,Type=Xover,Count=179,mcuTs=0x000DC827,fpgaTs=0xDB3C,lp-isD=1,lp-xoD=2344,alid=65535,cdr=65535,vhpn=65535,va=65535',
          '14:14:12.295 0,Type=Bndry,Count=88,mcuTs=0x000DCB00,fpgaTs=0x9DEC,lp-isD=1,lp-xoD=2344,alid=65535,cdr=65535,vhpn=65535,va=65535',
          '14:14:12.295 0,Type=IsXover,Count=136,mcuTs=0x000DC822,lp-isD=1,lp-xoD=2344,alid=65535,cdr=65535,vhpn=65535,va=65535']
```

I am trying to store `'alid=*****'` and `'vhpn=*****'` into another list called 'resultList'. I have code that finds a specific character and split it until the next comma:

```
for string in myList:
    mcuTimes1 = string[string.rfind('alid')+0:].split(',')[0]
    mcuTime1.append(mcuTimes1)
```

But the problem is because `'alid=*****'` and `'vhpn=*****'` are not consecutive (one after another) in the list I can't get both of them together (if I try to get both of them together with my code it will include `'cdr=*****'` as well).  I was wondering if anybody knows how to get two different parts of a list?

**UPDATE**:
I can't use **regex**
I want the result to look like this:

```
['alid=65535,vhpn=65535', 'alid=65535,vhpn=65535', 'alid=65535,vhpn=65535']
```

Comment: What happened to the other solutions you got? Did it turned not to be generic enough? This really gives me the impression of you ask X but need Y.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regular expressions here:

```
matches = [','.join(re.findall(r'(alid=\d+|vhpn=\d+)', i)) for i in myList]
```

Output:

```
['alid=65535,vhpn=65535', 'alid=65535,vhpn=65535', 'alid=65535,vhpn=65535']
```

Regex explanation:

```
(                                     // matching group 1
    alid=\d+                          // matches alid= followed by 1 or more digits
      |                               // OR
    vhpn=\d+                          // matches vhpn= followed by 1 or more digits
)                                     // end of matching group 1
```

A solution *not* using regex:

```
matches = []

for s in myList:
  options = s.split(',')
  found = []

  for option in options:
    if option[:option.find('=')] in {'alid', 'vhpn'}:
      found.append(option)

  matches.append(','.join(found))

print(matches)
```

Output:

```
['alid=65535,vhpn=65535', 'alid=65535,vhpn=65535', 'alid=65535,vhpn=65535']
```

Comment: Thank you but I can't use regex and I want each alid and vhpn to be stored in the same element please look at my update on the original post.

Comment: @seyet Then state it in your question!